# Does `sudo` need a password?

Tags: sudo, chmod

I've seen so many questions about using `sudo` without a password, but my question is, does `sudo` *need* a password?

I've read on some sites that `sudo` allow us to execute a command with privilege of root user without password. But whenever I try to execute `chmod` with `sudo` it requires a password, not of the root account but the password I use to log into Ubuntu.

Are passwords for root and system administrator different?

Comment: Related: [I can use sudo but I can't use su due to a password Authentication failure, shouldn't both be the same password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931528/i-can-use-sudo-but-i-cant-use-su-due-to-a-password-authentication-failure-shou/931531#931531)

Comment: Did you read `man sudo` and `man sudo.conf` before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root password and system admin passwords are different. A system will have only one root password but many system admin passwords.

Some users will be given the privilege to run the `sudo` command. Usually system admins will have this privilege so that they don't need the root password to run sudo. If the user doesn't have that privilege, they need the root password to run `sudo`.